# I want to store user data as a subcollection of the admin document in the Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The Signup admin activity stores its details in the ADMIN collection document (admin name) but when I add professor details (through the admin portal) as a subcollection to the admin document using uid, it generates a new document with the name of uid.

[Database snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsVSB.png)

How can I store the details of the user/professor in a current admin document as a subcollection?
Please help me Thanks.

Declaration:

```
FirebaseAuth auth;
String userId;
FirebaseFirestore firestore;
```

Initializing and Fetching uid:

```
firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
userId = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Passing userId from Document:

```
 DocumentReference documentReference =  firestore.collection("Admin").document(userId).collection("Professor").document(professorname);
                                    Map<String, String> Professor = new HashMap<>();
                                    Professor.put("Name", professorname);
                                    Professor.put("Email", email);
                                    Professor.put("Phone", phone);
                                    Professor.put("Desgination",desig);
                                    Professor.put("Department",dept);
                                    documentReference.set(Professor).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
                                    {...}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost 300 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `userId` does not correspond to the `name` you defined when creating the admin document. So when you use this document reference: `DocumentReference documentReference =  firestore.collection("Admin").document(userId).collection("Professor").document(professorname);` a new document is created because `userId` does not exist in your database.
Make sure that `userId` corresponds to the `name` (id in the database) and it should then work as expected.